# How to add a parameter to the URL according to the filter option that the user chooses in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making an advanced filter feature where users can filter post results according to the selected category.

And I want my url like this: `https://localhost/unairevent/event/list_event/category[] = 2 & category[] = 40`

(the category string in the URL is taken from the filter option that the user chooses using multiselect)

How to add strings to the URL according to the filter options that the user chooses?

---

I've tried using a method like this :

```
<section class="box text-center">
        <?php 
        $sort = $this->input->post('sort');
        $category = $this->input->post("get_kategori_acara_css[]");
        $interest = $this->input->post("get_interest_acara_css[]");
        ?>

   <?php echo form_open("acara/list_acara/".$category);?>
    <div class="form-inline">
      <p>Advanced Sort & Filter</p>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" name="sort">
            <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Sort By </option>
            <option value="acara.id_acara">Newest</option>
            <option value="hits_acara.hits">Trending</option>
            <option value="tanggal_mulai_acara">Upcoming</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo form_dropdown('', $get_checkbox_kategori, '', $get_kategori_acara_css); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo form_dropdown('', $get_checkbox_interest, '', $get_interest_acara_css); ?>
        </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
  </section>
```

But Shown error like this :

> Message: Array to string conversion

---

Show error image

[image: Show error image]

The advanced filter image

[image: The advanced filter image]

Comment: `/category[] = 2 & category[] = 40` is most likely not what you want. Do you mean it should be a query string? `?category[]=2&category[]=40` (the `?` in the URL is important since that's indicating that what comes after is the query string).

Comment: Check out [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). That function can convert arrays to query strings.

Comment: Are you using Controller in Codeigniter ?

Answer (score 0):

concert and conference dropdown name as an array can hold multiple selected values.

```
<select multiple name="concert[]" >
```

Printing the concert array at PHP end will display all the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

This you can use GET parameter instead of using URL segments. The initial test should be done through URLs and once you completed the testing try to send the parameter from client side like JavaScript

Example:

> http://localhost/unairevent?category=1,2,3,4

Using Codeigniter you can get like this:

`$this->input->get('category');
/* This will return value - 1,2,3,4 */`

Now you can split this by comma and push to array.

`$category_array = explode(",", $this->input->get('category'));`

In order to keep the input selection session you can use this method

`<?= (in_array("name_of_cat", $category_array)) ? "selected" : "" ?>`

Comment: sorry, that problem is solved. But shown a new problem -_-

Show error like this => Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: I use codeigniter. 

This is my view code : https://pastebin.com/rPtQvcdK
This is my controller code : https://pastebin.com/mxkS1LEk
My error message : http://prntscr.com/m4dsfb

Comment: get_kategori_acara_css[]=6, don't use `[]` in your URL just use get_kategori_acara_css=6,5,3

Comment: You cannot pass the array in string like this `'name'  => 'get_kategori_acara_css[]',`

Comment: You can use custom form drop down instead using `form_dropdown('shirts', $options, $shirts_on_sale);`

Comment: Your code has so many issues and need to fix one by one so this comment is not the place where you can expect for your help

Comment: Ask a simple question and describe your requirements without typing any code so the community will guide you for that, then you can follow the way instead correcting so many issues in your code

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get url like this

https://localhost/unairevent/event/list_event/category[] = 2 & category[] = 40

instead of these 
at your event controller at list_event method ... you can have those things when you use get method... than your url should be
https://localhost/unairevent/event/list_event?category[]=2&category[]=40

and change it

```
$category = $this->input->post("get_kategori_acara_css[]");
$interest = $this->input->post("get_interest_acara_css[]");
```

to .. it seems like only prob

```
$category = $this->input->post("get_kategori_acara_css");
$interest = $this->input->post("get_interest_acara_css");
```

your variable $category and $interest will be array if you have set it as array before...

try to debug your error then... add these after you set variables ..

```
var_dump($category);
var_dump($interest);
```

if it shows you string ... there you go ... every thing is fine ... remove var_dump and have fun.. else .. check it ... that why you are getting it as array.. and pass those thing as string...

at your view .. change these two things...  change your `sort` to `sort[]` and it works ..

```
<select class="form-control" name="sort[]" multiple>
```